# Null Pointer Exception (Looping through an array of objects)

Tags: java

I haven't used Java in a while so I'm rusty. I have a method that returns an array of objects. In my main, I created a new object array and set that new array of objects to the return array of the method. Something like this:

```
Obj[] main_arr = new Obj[100];
main_arr = method(x);

for (int i = 0; i < main_arr.length; i ++){
  if(main_arr[i].number == 1) {  // the error seems to be here
      // do some stuff
  }
  else {
      // do some stuff
  }

}
```

I am trying to loop through main_arr and access the things in this object array, however I get a Null Pointer Exception. I've been in the debugger tool and main_arr seems to have the correct content. Any ideas why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to help. Please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Add your loop code segmemet

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: I've edited the code segments!

Comment: By the way, it is wasteful to initialize `main_arr` to a new array if the next statement is just going to assign another value to the same variable.

Comment: Which statement is causing the NPE? In general, when you ask a question about an exception, you should show the stack trace.

Comment: Updated! I added where it was throwing an error

Comment: If that line is throwing the NPE, then `main_arr[i]` is null.  The problem is almost certainly in the method where the array is populated, rather than in the code presented here.

Comment: I've been in the debugger tool, main_arr in my code isn't NULL, but correctly populated, hence why I was confused about the NPE

Comment: It is not `main_arr` that is `null`. *Some elements* of `main_arr` are `null`. This could happen, for example, if `main_arr` has 100 elements but only the first 10 were actually assigned a value.

Comment: ah thank you @cybersam, that's probably the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some elements of `main_arr` are null.

This could happen, for example, if `main_arr` has 100 elements but only the first 10 were actually assigned a value.

Comment: that was  a quick fix, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's main_arr.length() not main_arr.length

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, plus length() is for strings i thought

Comment: just noticed that after the int i = 0 you put , instead of ; also I was wrong about the ()

Comment: that was a typo lmfao, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Java Array Object **does not have a method to get its length**. Youneed to use the ‘array length attribute’, like this:

```
int arrayLength = myArray.length;
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength - 1; i++) {

   if (myArray[i] == whatever) {
      //do some job
   }
}
```

Credits: https://www.edureka.co/blog/array-length-in-java/